# I wish to insert a "login" button instead of the contact form, in Prestashop 1.6

Tags: authentication, button, prestashop

I wish to insert a "login" button instead of the contact form, in Prestashop 1.6.
I have it in 5 languages.
I also have a captcha installed, but spammers still send messages using the form.
The idea is that only logged-in customers will be able to send messages.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in `/override/classes/controller/FrontController.php`

```
<?php

class FrontController extends FrontControllerCore
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        if (!$this->context->customer->isLogged() && $this->php_self == 'contact')
        {
            Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=authentication?back=index');
        }
    }
}
```

Then go to `/var/cache/dev` and `/var/cache/prod` and delete **class_index.php**